# Are these two if statements equivalent?

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

I am trying to reduce the function cognitive complexity required by SonarQube, I am wondering, are these two if statements equivalent?

The first statement:

```
           if (
              currentRef &&
              currentRef.current &&
              currentRef.current.value.length === 0
            )
```

I want to replace it by :

```
            if (
              currentRef?.current?.value.length === 0
            )
```

Comment: it could be some odd corner cases, that maybe this two won't be equal; for example if
we have something like this: currentRef = { current: 0}
the second one throw an error.
but the first one in not.

it depends on the currentRef

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Optional chaining returns `undefined` in case of an invalid reference. MDN docs state:

> The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead
> of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the
> expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. When used
> with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does
> not exist.

However, keep this in mind:

> Optional chaining cannot be used on a non-declared root object, but can be used with an undefined root object.

---

### Example

```js
const dog = {'foo': 0};

console.log(dog?.foo === 0);
console.log(dog?.bar === 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The two statements in your question are equivalent, which means that for a given value, they will both return either `true` or `false`.

[See this playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyCArlFBOAPwBcOBxTyAbnADakT2kgDWIdAHcQAbQC6jYgF8Cs-ARi8EYYOhDIAJugDK6ALYQwAC1ABzABRwA+gAc4UOPrppMASnot0wTQ0LFgGCs7BydkADJwqSIbe0d9ADoyCiowCKj-GJD4pPJKcAS2TggE9iozE2QAXhrkAAY3PEzmBHUAZ3Qy0vRLAHIACQh2diwAdXQodk1etwBuaOR5BcDguKdqXJSaQo4uUvLKmqr6xoWmVpAOrpG+weGxiamZ+eb5JfxtPUMTcws55AA9ADkIJkDc2gRPgYjKYQJYmuc8ql6AjmEQilx6BIFm9-kCwT02sgBkMRshxpNpsgwEJgEggA)

It is important to mention that

```
if (currentRef?.current?.value.length === 0)
```

is the preferred syntax for these statements, since they also allow you to use a default value using nullish concealing.

No nullish concealing:

```
if (currentRef?.current?.value.length === 0) 
// computes to false if 'currentRef or 'current' is undfined'
```

With nullish concealing:

```
if ((currentRef?.current?.value.length ?? 0) === 0) 
// computes to true if 'currentRef or 'current' is undfined'
```